# No duplicate one try/catch by waterfall function (using async waterfall)

Tags: node.js, try-catch, waterfall

I'm using async waterfall and i've got a question about try/catch error.

I wan't to dodge this syntax method with one global try/catch and no duplicate a try/catch by function :

```
async.waterfall([
function (callback) {
  try {
     this.foo() // Ok
     this.bar() // Method bar doesn't exist so without try/catch node will crash
  } catch(ex) {
     //print err
  }
},
function (callback) {
  try {
     //Again & again
  } catch(ex) {
     //print err
  }
}
//... function() with try catch ...
], function(err, result) {
   //Do something
})
```

Comment: Why not just remove the try/catch and do something more like `return 'foo' in this || something else`

Comment: Can be ok but how do you do if you have 2 methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you seek a more robust error handling system; try this:

```
var async = require('async');


function callbackErrorHandler(fn, callback) {
  try {
    fn()
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err);
  }
}

async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
   callbackErrorHandler(function() {
     throw new Error('error1');
   }, callback);
  },

  function(callback) {
    callbackErrorHandler(function() {
      throw new Error('error2');
    }, callback);
  }
],
//final
function(err, result) {
  console.log(err);
});


/**
 * Using Promises
 */
 var async = require('async');

//promises
var Promises = require('bluebird');

function callbackErrorHandler(fn) {
  return new Promises(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      resolve(fn()); //should return something
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      callbackErrorHandler(function() {
        throw new Error('error1');
      })
      .error(callback)
    },

    function(callback) {
      callbackErrorHandler(function() {
        throw new Error('error2');
      })
      .error(callback)

    }
  ],
  //final
  function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry but it's wrong. I tested a simple code and inexisting method crash my node server even if i've implemented error result in final callback

Comment: Yep but it's not very clean :/

Comment: That would be up to you to make it "clean" according to your standards. You could utilize promises to achieve this. But, that's not the question at hand and would be off topic from this thread.

Comment: Ok thanks, but with promises it will be the same problem no ? Or you can try catch promises ?

Comment: edited to show what it would potentially look like using promises

Answer (score 0):

This script no longer print in final callback and crash node server :

Test this and try to rename test() by testt()

```
'use strict'

var async     = require('./lib/node_modules/async')

function test()
{
    console.log("hi !")
}
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    callback(null)
  },
  function(callback){
    test()
    callback(null, null)
  }], function (err, result) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("got an error !")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("everyting is ok")
        }
  }
)
```